# Can Python print a function definition?

Tags: python

In JavaScript, one can print out the definition of a function.  Is there a way to accomplish this in Python?

(Just playing around in interactive mode, and I wanted to read a module without open().  I was just curious).

Comment: You have the source for the function.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: And from interactive mode you can use help(function) to display the docstring for the function.

Comment: There's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function

Comment: @S.Lott if there is a way that is good. for example beginners can print a decorated function and easily see changes.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

If you are importing the function, you can use [`inspect.getsource`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource):

```
>>> import re
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(re.compile)
def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
```

This *will* work  in the interactive prompt, but apparently only on objects that are imported (not objects defined within the interactive prompt). And of course it will only work if Python can find the source code (so not on built-in objects, C libs, .pyc files, etc)

Comment: Functions that are created at runtime (including the interactive prompt) don't have a file or linenumber either, which makes sense

Comment: What about printing a function definition that I defined earlier on in the current interactive Python interpreter?  Is this possible?

Comment: @GL2014: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer and inspect.getsource() *DOES* work on interactive (ipython3) defined funciton in Python 3.6.9 (Ubuntu).

Comment: for python3, use ```print(inspect.getsource(re.compile))```

Answer (score 129):

If you're using [iPython](http://ipython.org/), you can use **`function_name?`** to get help, and **`function_name??`** will print out the source, if it can.

Comment: sometimes you need to separate the function into another line to call ? e.g. model.function?? doesn't work but f = model.function; f?? works

Answer (score 31):

This is the way I figured out how to do it:

```
import inspect as i
import sys
sys.stdout.write(i.getsource(MyFunction))
```

This takes out the new line characters and prints the function out nicely

Comment: Broken example there, it should be i.getsource(MyFunction).

Comment: Why use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()`?

Answer (score 13):

While I'd generally agree that `inspect` is a good answer, I'd disagree that you can't get the source code of objects defined in the interpreter.  If you use `dill.source.getsource` from [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill), you can get the source of functions and lambdas, even if they are defined interactively.
It also can get the code for from bound or unbound class methods and functions defined in curries... however, you might not be able to compile that code without the enclosing object's code.

```
>>> from dill.source import getsource
>>> 
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> squared = lambda x:x**2
>>> 
>>> print getsource(add)
def add(x,y):
  return x+y

>>> print getsource(squared)
squared = lambda x:x**2

>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self, x):
...     return x*x+x
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> 
>>> print getsource(f.bar)
def bar(self, x):
    return x*x+x

>>>
```

Comment: sometimes it doesn't work directly with: **getsource(my_function)**, but then I could get it to work with **getsource(my_function.func_code)**

Answer (score 5):

Use `help(function)` to get the function description.

You can read more about `help()` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/help-function-in-python/).

Comment: didnot have the source defined in help for me.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but I just wanted to clarify a few things.

I Googled for a solution for the problem and discovered this question, and I found in IPython you can use `inspect.getsource` to get functions defined in the interpreter.

But you can't use it to get definitions of functions defined interactively in the plain Python shell (i.e. `Python.exe`).

**IPython 8.4.0 on Python 3.10.5**

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import inspect
   ...: def fibonacci(n):
   ...:     s = []
   ...:     a, b = 0, 1
   ...:     for i in range(n):
   ...:         s.append(a)
   ...:         a, b = b, a + b
   ...:     return s
   ...:
   ...: fibonacci(16)
Out[1]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]

In [2]: print(inspect.getsource(fibonacci))
def fibonacci(n):
    s = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        s.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    return s
```

**Python 3.10.5**

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> def fibonacci(n):
...     s = []
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     for i in range(n):
...         s.append(a)
...         a, b = b, a + b
...     return s
...
>>> fibonacci(16)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]
>>> print(inspect.getsource(fibonacci))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 1147, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 1129, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\inspect.py", line 958, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you are importing the function, you can use inspect.getsource. This will work in the interactive prompt, but apparently only on objects that are imported (not objects defined within the interactive prompt)

It also doesn't work on many types of dynamically executed code, such as with `exec()`. In Python v3.3+, you can use `inspect.signature()`. It appers this is what `help()` also uses internally. This also works with interactively defined things.

Example:

```
import inspect

code = """
def sum(a:int, b:int=5) -> int:
  return a + b
"""

exec(code)
print(sum(2))
print("def sum{}".format(inspect.signature(sum)))
```

This results in:

```
7
def sum(a: int, b: int = 5) -> int
```

Side-note: Yes, `exec()` is dangerous. If you don't know why, you shouldn't use it. It's used here purely for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the __doc__ keyword:

```
#print the class description
print string.__doc__
#print function description
print open.__doc__
```

Comment: That's the description, not the definition.

Comment: for many builtins (as a rule, functions defined in C modules), it includes the function signature as well, but not in general.

Comment: While in the interactive shell "help(object)" will display this in a more navigable way.

Comment: @kaizer A function signature is not a definition either. What `__doc__` _actually_ returns is whatever the author of the code put in the doc string (the triple quoted string). Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I think definition is ambiguous here. To me it could mean the docstring or the code text or both or even the code object at a stretch

Comment: @Am, if you put backquotes around `__doc__` it will show the underscores instead of making it bold

Comment: @gnibbler Python is not ambiguous about what function definitions are: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Comment: to my opinion, the question was about about functional help on functions, inteli-sense kind. if @eddie asked about exact definition, then my answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the `__doc__` in the function, take `hog()` function as example:
You can see the usage of `hog()` like this:

```
from skimage.feature import hog

print hog.__doc__
```

The output will be:

```
Extract Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) for a given image.
Compute a Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) by

    1. (optional) global image normalisation
    2. computing the gradient image in x and y
    3. computing gradient histograms
    4. normalising across blocks
    5. flattening into a feature vector

Parameters
----------
image : (M, N) ndarray
    Input image (greyscale).
orientations : int
    Number of orientation bins.
pixels_per_cell : 2 tuple (int, int)
    Size (in pixels) of a cell.
cells_per_block  : 2 tuple (int,int)
    Number of cells in each block.
visualise : bool, optional
    Also return an image of the HOG.
transform_sqrt : bool, optional
    Apply power law compression to normalise the image before
    processing. DO NOT use this if the image contains negative
    values. Also see `notes` section below.
feature_vector : bool, optional
    Return the data as a feature vector by calling .ravel() on the result
    just before returning.
normalise : bool, deprecated
    The parameter is deprecated. Use `transform_sqrt` for power law
    compression. `normalise` has been deprecated.

Returns
-------
newarr : ndarray
    HOG for the image as a 1D (flattened) array.
hog_image : ndarray (if visualise=True)
    A visualisation of the HOG image.

References
----------
* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients

* Dalal, N and Triggs, B, Histograms of Oriented Gradients for
  Human Detection, IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer
  Vision and Pattern Recognition 2005 San Diego, CA, USA

Notes
-----
Power law compression, also known as Gamma correction, is used to reduce
the effects of shadowing and illumination variations. The compression makes
the dark regions lighter. When the kwarg `transform_sqrt` is set to
``True``, the function computes the square root of each color channel
and then applies the hog algorithm to the image.
```

Comment: The question was about function definition not function docstring.