# Is it possible to print a function as a string in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Python print a function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562759/can-python-print-a-function-definition)

In Javascript, it is possible to print a function's code as a string?

Example in Javascript:

```
function thisFunctionPrintsItself(){
    return thisFunctionPrintsItself.toString();
}
```

Is it possible to do the same in Python?

Comment: @olly_uk I have tried it in Javascript, but not in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but the result isn't useful since everything is compiled to bytecode first.

```
def printItself():
    print repr(printItself.func_code.co_code)
```

You can also use the `dis` module for disassembly, but the results aren't garuenteed to be portable.

```
def disassembleItself():
    print __import__('dis').dis(disassembleItself)
```

Comment: This is what I got for the first function output:     't\x00\x00t\x01\x00j\x02\x00j\x03\x00\x83\x01\x00GHd\x00\x00S'

Comment: @Anderson - exactly, it's compiled to bytecode.

Comment: Is it possible to actually print the function's source code, as in Javascript?

Comment: Wait... the other answer explains this. :)

Comment: It's possible in some cases, but only if the source is available. Also, it won't work if the definition is changed at run time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo ():
    import inspect
    return inspect.getsource(foo)

print (foo())
```

Here, the inspect module reads the source files, so it won't work if they're missing (and just the `.pyc` or `.pyo` modules are being used) or the function was compiled on-the-fly, in the interactive interpreter or otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to write a function that can take another function as a parameter, and then print the function's source?

Comment: That's exactly what `inspect.getsource` does.