# Appending an attribute to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am not sure exactly what this means or how it is used, but I came across this functionality when it comes to a function. I am able to dynamically add attributes to a function.

What is the use of this and how does it happen? I mean it's a function name after all, how can we add attributes to it dynamically?

```
def impossible():
    print "Adding a bool"

impossible.enabled = True 
# I was able to just do this. And this is a function, how does this add up?

print(impossible.enabled) # No attribute error. Output: True
```

Comment: It’s not a function *name*; it’s a function, and it’s like any other value. Any type can permit or forbid new attributes.

Comment: Does the same apply for a class as well?

Comment: The same which? =) Classes are also like any other values, and also are a type that permit new attributes, yes. Classes aren’t functions, though (try `isinstance(SomeClass, type(some_function))`).

Comment: Is there a way to print the definition of the function, in case i do that would i be able to see the new attribute appended to it?

Comment: [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562759/can-python-print-a-function-definition), but an attribute on a function isn’t part of a function’s definition anyway. You can use `dir(impossible)` to see all the names of attributes on it.

Comment: Yea makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169013/discussion-between-abhishek-and-ry).

Answer (score 3):

in python functions are objects, they have all sorts of inner attributes and they can also have  the `__dict__` attribute, and like any other object anything in `__dict__` is a variable of that object.you can see it if you print it before and after `impossible.enabled`

```
def impossible():
    print "Adding a bool"

print(impossible.__dict__) #  {}
impossible.enabled = True 
print(impossible.__dict__) #  {'enabled': True}
```

this doesn't change the function in any way since most of the time `__dict__` is empty and holds no special value in a function.
in fact its a bit useful since you could use this in a function to store static variables without cluttering your global names

Comment: randomName = 'Jack'  # Is this an object? ( As in randomName)

Comment: no strings, numbers, booleans and None are primitives not objects

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: This is Python. Yes, strings, numbers, booleans, and `None` are objects – they’re just immutable. (`isinstance(True, object)`)

Comment: @Abhishek: It *is* an object. Every value in Python is an object.

Comment: So why can't we add attributes to a string object? Like randomName.Enabled = True

Comment: Is it because it's immutable?

Comment: @Ry they are literally objects but they behave differently because there is no way to recreate any of them in pure python

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes, it’s because it’s immutable.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: They behave differently in what respect?

Comment: @Ry︁ then what about lists? That's mutable

Comment: @Abhishek: Sorry, I thought “is it because it’s immutable?” was a follow-up to a different question. Something immutable can’t have attributes added to it, but things can prevent new attributes from being added without being immutable too.

Answer (score 0):

The name `impossible` points to an object that represents the function. You're setting a property on this object (which python allows you to do on all objects by default):

```
>>> def foo():
...   print("test")
...
>>> dir(foo)
['__call__', ..., 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
>>> foo.a = 'test'
>>> dir(foo)
['__call__', ..., 'a', ...]
```

Since this object implements `__call__`, it can be called as a function - you can implement your own class that defines `__call__` and it'll also be allowed to be called as a function:

```
>>> class B:
...   def __call__(self, **kw):
...     print(kw)
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b()    
{}
>>> b(foo='bar')
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

If you create a new function, you can see that you haven't done anything to the *definition* of a function (its class), just the object that represents the original function:

```
>>> def bar():
...   print("ost")
...
>>> dir(bar)
['__call__', ..., 'func_closure', ...]
```

This new object does not have a property named `a`, since you haven't set one on the object `bar` points to.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use a function attribute to implement a simple counter, like so:

```
def count():
    try:
        count.counter += 1
    except AttributeError:
        count.counter = 1
    return count.counter
```

Repeatedly calling "count()" yields: 1, 2, 3, ...