# How to print the contents of a function onto the output window in Python?

Tags: python, function, printing, output

So I have a piece of code such as

```
def math():
    x = 2
    y = 4
    z = x + y
```

What I'd like to be able to do is print out the contents of this function somehow, so that what appears in the output window is:

```
 x = 2
 y = 4
 z = x + y
```

How could I print this out as a string from the function?

I tried things such as:

```
print(math())
```

but that just calls the function
or

```
print(math)
```

which doesn't give my anything.  And

```
print("math()")
```

just prints out the name.

Comment: To clarify, you want to print out the actual lines of code in your function as raw text?

Comment: @UnsanitizedInput  yes exactly, as if I'm printing the contents as a string.

Comment: May I ask what the reason for wanting to do this is?

Comment: @UnsanitizedInput So basically this functions will be executed by a pressing a button on a UI, but I'll have a section in my UI where a person can click a button and generate the code from the function, essentially isolating the code from the overall UI, but for them to copy the code it'll need to be printed out on the output. Because some people using the script may want to bind the code to a hotkey and use it that way, instead of having to go to the UI every time and clicking the button. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Cireo from what I've seen, that solutions works on imported functions only, not ones that are defined within the interactive prompt

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458391/1491895) shows how to do it for functions defined interactively.

Comment: The solutions don't work more generally because Python simply doesn't always save the source code anywhere.