# Return function code

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

How do I return the code of my function?
The func_name method works as expected but not the func_code

```
>>> def testthis(): print 'test successful'
>>> testthis()
test successful

>>> testthis.func_name
'testthis'
>>> testthis.func_code
<code object testthis at 0124D728, file "<pyshell#281>", line 1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> inspect.getsourcelines(function_name)

for getting he code.

```
In [1]: def testthis(): print "hello"

In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: inspect.getsourcelines(testthis)
Out[3]: ([u'def testthis(): print "hello"\n'], 1)
```