# Is there a way to determine if an argument passed to a function is assigned or literal in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to get python to determine if the value passed to a function is an assigned variable or an unassigned literal data type. Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

pseudocode:

```
def func(var):
     if isliteral(var):
         return 'foo'
    else:
         return 'bar'

var1 = func('source_str') # returns 'foo'

x = 'source_str'

var2 = func(x) # returns 'bar'
```

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Pls state why you want to know this. There is almost certainly a better way to solve the underlying issue.

Comment: I'm adding properties to a class and setting the attributes dynamically. I'm trying to get so that if the argument pasted when the object is created is  named variable then the attribute will be set to the variables name otherwise use the value pasted and a index number as the attribute name.

Comment: "I'm trying to get so that if the argument pasted when the object is created is named variable then the attribute will be set to the variables name" Why would you want to do this? This seems like a bad idea. In general, there is no good way to accomplish this, there is no real distinction between the two, and it is certainly not reasonable to treat them differently. It may be possible doing some sort of introspection, maybe even of the byte code. All in all, not a good idea.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga. I thought it would be possible. But, it doesn't sound like it is at the time. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827543/is-there-anyway-to-get-the-names-of-passed-arguments-to-a-function-in-python

Comment: A potential sensible use case for this is in an SQL driver, where you'd want to check that parameterization was being used for normal queries instead of string substitution (so closing off a whole class of injection attacks).