# How is types.SimpleNamespace implemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I noticed the `types.SimpleNamespace` class seems to be recursively implemented. In the `types` module, the class is defined as `type(sys.implementation)`. However, `type(sys.implementation)` simply returns `types.SimpleNamespace`, which wouldn't be possible, since both names rely on each other to be available. How is `types.SimpleNamespace` actually implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `type(sys.implementation) is types.SimpleNamespace`, but that doesn’t mean that the latter is the **source** of the type (and `types.` doesn’t appear as the *output* of anything).  Like most types exposed in `types`, `SimpleNamespace` is defined in the implementation (in C for CPython), and `types` just gives **names** to whatever circumlocutions are “convenient” for accessing the type.  (`TracebackType` is obtained from actually throwing and catching a dummy exception!)  The `sys` module actually uses the built-in type, along with other shenanigans like creating `version_info` even though the type can’t be instantiated (afterwards).

Comment: About what you said about `types` giving names to built-in types -- that's true, but `type(lambda: 0)` doesn't come out as `types.FunctionType`, it's just `function`. It's still a good answer, though.

Comment: @fluffyyboii: Here, “gives names to” means “allows access by name”, not “stores a name into”.  See the [cat-on-the-porch story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827710/8586227), although unlike most objects types *do* know their own name that might be (say) `function` instead of whatever you used to get them.