# Python - os.path doesn't exist: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python, path, python-import, corruption, built-in

Investigating a strange error that I started getting all of a sudden with gdb-python, I reduced it down to this:

```
C:\Users\User>python -i
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> dir(os.path)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
>>> dir(os)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Looking through some other `'module' object has no attribute` answers, the most common suggestion is that there must be another rogue `os.py` somewhere in `sys.path`, and that it was getting loaded, rather than the built-in one. But I checked in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and in the current directory, and there wasn't any other `os.py`.

So I looked for a way to find the name of the file where an entity was defined, and unsurprisingly, Python has [such a facility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427533/1143274) in the form of the `inspect` module.

```
>>> inspect.getsourcelines(os)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programs\Python273\lib\inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Programs\Python273\lib\inspect.py", line 527, in findsource
    sourcefile = getsourcefile(object)
  File "C:\Programs\Python273\lib\inspect.py", line 451, in getsourcefile
    if os.path.exists(filename):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

So `inspect` was relying on `os.path`, and then I ran out of ideas.

I haven't installed anything new recently. The only thing that happened was a forced shutdown that I had to do, which might have coincided with running a Python script, since I was running a short Python script in a loop repeatedly when the machine became unresponsive and the forced shutdown occurred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time, I figured it out. Looking under `C:\Programs\Python273\Lib`, I noticed that `os.pyc` was much smaller in size than `os.py` and `os.pyo`, while for the other modules, `abc.pyc` is equal in size to `abc.pyo` and slightly smaller than `abc.py`. Looking inside `os.pyc`, it contained only:

```
^Có
\{GOc^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@@^@^@^@s^D^@^@^@d^@^@S(
^A^@^@^@N(^@^@^@^@(^@^@^@^@(^@^@^@^@(^@^@^@^@s^_^@^@
^@C:\Programs\Python273\lib\os.pyt^H^@^@^@<module>^A
^@^@^@s^@^@^@^@
```

(This is how it shows up in Vim.) (Note: the `t` at the end of `os.pyt` is not part of the filename.)

Deleting this file (and two other `.pyc` files with the same story) solved the problem.

So what happened must be that `python` was recompiling `os` into `os.pyc` for some reason (why? if it's already compiled before?) and has output the first part of the file (which was valid as a file by itself), then the forced shutdown occurred before it had a chance to output the rest. So it's an example of the frustrating problems that happen when operations are not atomic.

Also, it turns out I could have tracked it down faster, because doing

```
>>> inspect.getfile(os)
'C:\\Programs\\Python273\\lib\\os.pyc'
```

still works when `os.path` isn't available.

Comment: You could have also used `os.__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and C:\Python27\Lib\os.py doesn't have readlink() function at all. Searched the Lib and found 6 paces there it's being used but no definition:

Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
C:\Python27\Lib\pdb.py(1194):                 dirname = os.readlink(dirname)
C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py(952):             os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filepath),os.readlink(filepath)))
C:\Python27\Lib\posixpath.py(386):         resolved = os.readlink(path)
C:\Python27\Lib\rexec.py(146):     ok_posix_names = ('error', 'fstat', 'listdir', 'lstat', 'readlink',
C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py(183):                 linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
C:\Python27\Lib\tarfile.py(1873):             linkname = os.readlink(name)
```