# Is there any way to get source code inside context manager as string?

Tags: python

Source code of function [can be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427533/1113207) received with `inspect.getsourcelines(func)` function. Is there any way to do same for context manager?

```
with test():
    print('123')

# How to get "print('123')" as line here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about this solution?

```
import traceback


class ContextManagerContent(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        return

    def __exit__(self, _type, value, _traceback):
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        f, last_line = self._get_origin_info(stack)

        with open(f) as fin:
            lines = list(fin)

        search = 'with {cls_name}'.format(cls_name=self.__class__.__name__)
        for i, x in enumerate(lines[:last_line + 1][::-1]):
            if search in x:
                first_line = len(lines) - i
                break

        selected_lines = lines[first_line:last_line + 1]
        print ''.join(selected_lines)

    def _get_origin_info(self, stack):
        origin = None
        for i, x in enumerate(stack[::-1]):
            if x[2] == '__exit__':
                origin = stack[::-1][i + 1]
                break

        return origin[0], origin[1] - 1


with ContextManagerContent():
    print '123'
    print '456'
    print '789'
```

If you save this in a `.py` file and run it you can see being printed the numbers 123, 456 and 789, after that you can see the block of the context manager.

Notice that I did not handle possibile exceptions or formatting of the output, and some parts can be improved, but I think that this is a good starting point.

Comment: Er, you should be getting firstline from the `__enter__`, not a bogus search.

Comment: Yeah why not get the TB from __enter__? then you could avoid all the exception kind of cases

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution inspired from @se7entyse7en's answer. I think it is a bit cleaner and more efficient this way

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def debug(string):
    # before block
    cf = currentframe()
    first_line =  cf.f_back.f_back.f_lineno
    filename = getframeinfo(cf.f_back.f_back).filename

    yield

    # after block
    cf = currentframe()
    last_line =  cf.f_back.f_back.f_lineno
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[first_line:last_line]
    print(string + '\n' + ''.join(lines).rstrip())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with debug("show this code in stdout:"):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        a, b = b, a
```