# Is there a programmatic way to print the definition of a dynamically created function in python?

Tags: python, function

I was studying about *inner functions*. One of its uses is in closure and factory functions.

Consider the following example I found [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/)

```
def generate_power(number):
    """
    Examples of use:

    >>> raise_two = generate_power(2)
    >>> raise_three = generate_power(3)
    >>> print(raise_two(7))
    128
    >>> print(raise_three(5))
    243
    """

    # define the inner function ...
    def nth_power(power):
        return number ** power
    # ... which is returned by the factory function

    return nth_power
```

If I were to run the use case from this example, it would create a new function **raise_two**.

Can we print function definition of **raise_two**? (making it easier to understand the whole concept)

**edit:**

This question requires an answer that is different from the ones found at [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function) as I've explained in the comment section.

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function), it would seem that getting the code of a function that is not explicitly defined in a file is not possible.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear?  For example, if we had the magic function:  `print_func_def(raise_two)`, what output would you expect?

Comment: `print(raise_two)` tells you 
`<function generate_power.<locals>.nth_power at 0x7f3331141c80>`. `print(raise_two.__closure__)` tells you `(<cell at 0x7f3332715588: int object at 0xa68a60>,)`. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Note that the function definition is not going to say `raise_two` or `2` anywhere in it. It'll just be the text of the `nth_power` definition. Closure variables are not substituted into the inner function at inner function definition time.

Comment: @RandomDavis There are some solutions provided in that answer. I didn't find my particular case solved though.

Comment: @mgilson May be something like nth_power(power):\nreturn 2 ** power.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I understand that raise_two will have its name replaced by nth_power, but wouldn't the definition of raise_two be something as above (with the 2?)
I had gone through the answers to the claimed duplicate question earlier - I don't want the format in which 'dis' presents the definition & 'dill' doesn't seem to be working for me, so I posted this question.