# How to get all the properties of a class in python

Tags: python, reflection

I have this class in python defined like this

```
class MyClass(object):
   @property
   def property1(self):
       # type: () -> pb.data.Property1

   @property
   def property2(self):
       # type: () -> pb.data.Property2
```

How can I use reflection to read all the properties that the class has
and then make a map from the property name to its class

something like

```
{"property1":"pb.data.Property1", "property2":"pb.data.Property2"}
```

Remember that the first line in each property is a comment. Is there a clear way to do it?

Comment: Why comments? Turn them into docstrings.

Comment: @bipll. They are kind of autogenerated. I can't change them

Comment: Autogenerated with what? You can modify the autogeneration tool to put annotations in a more pythonic way, you can add one more phase to code generation to turn comments into strings, you can do it manually per each source file under your control, what have you tried before admitting "I can't"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inspect.getmembers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) to get all the attribute values. Hopefully below code will help you out.

```
import inspect
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def property1(self):
        return 'pb.data.Property1'

    @property
    def property2(self):
        return 'pb.data.Property2'

    def get_attributes(self):
        attributes = inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=lambda a: not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
        return {d[0]:d[1] for d in attributes if not(d[0].startswith('__') and d[0].endswith('__'))}


MyClass().get_attributes()
```

***Output***: `{'property1': 'pb.data.Property1', 'property2': 'pb.data.Property2'}`