# How can I see the source code for the Python library "keyboard"?

Tags: python, keyboard

Let's say that I wanted to create my own library to be used in Python. How would I code a key press? How do I establish that without referencing the Python library of "keyboard"? I would love to be able to view the "keyboard" library that I import, in order to see how that library was created.

Thanks!

Comment: Do `import keyboard; print(keyboard.__file__)`, then open that file in the text editor of your choice. Alternatively, find the code on github.

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard? I just looked it up on https://pypi.org/ and followed the links to the source code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, in place of `_file_`, am I putting something like `_init_ or _main_`, or do you literally mean `_file_`? Because when I run that, I am getting:

`AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute '_file_'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the link. That was what I was looking for, I think. I'm still new to all of this so that's a lot of source code to look through.

Comment: I mean `__file__` with 2 underscores on each side.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `inspect` module.

Also possibly duplicate of this: [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)