# Sympy lambdify ImmutableDenseMatrix with numexpr

Tags: python, sympy, numexpr, lambdify

I try to accelerate the evaluation of a MutableDenseMatrix using lambdify. It works with the module 'numpy'. 'Numexpr' should be faster (as I need the evaluation to solve a large optimization problem).

A smaller example of what I am trying to do is given by

```
from sympy import symbols, cos, Matrix, lambdify

a11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22, u = symbols("a11 a12 a21 a22 b11 b12 b21 b22 u")
A = Matrix([[a11, a12], [a21, a22]])
B = Matrix([[b11, b12], [b21, b22]])
expr = A * (B ** 2) * cos(u) + A ** (-3 / 2)
f = lambdify((A, B), expr, modules='numexpr')
```

It raises the error

```
TypeError: numexpr cannot be used with ImmutableDenseMatrix
```

Is there a way to use lambdify for DenseMatrices? Or another idea how to speed up the evaluation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first it may make sense to see the actual code which sympy exports. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760092/4045774 `inspect.getsource(f)` After that there are many ways to optimize the implementation manually (Cython, Numba, Numexpr) or maybe also by a better vectorization strategy (Numpy)

Comment: The code is way too long to show it here. It returns an ndarray of size (2,1). The two entries are a long mix containing +, -, *, /, ** and sqrt. I hope this helps.

Comment: A small example (at least with the same input's and outputs) or a full one (pastebin ?) would be good. It looks like quite simple to optimize using numba or cython, but there may be some manual editing and a few optimizations necessary.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.pl/view/31defe71
x,y and z are integer scalars. s0,su,sv,suu,suv,svv,u and v are ndarrays of size(383,552). Thank you!

Comment: This is a working numexpr version including benchmark (3700x speedup) https://pastebin.pl/view/bb190db6 . But it would be a good idea to add an example with a smaller MutableDenseMatrix to write an answer on that. It might be useful for others. I also found this sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial but in this example a text editing is enough. You also had code errors in your pastebin (The function header is in between at line 3118)

Comment: Thank you very much. I edit the post, so its easier to give a precise answer. Would be really nice if you could explain what you did to get the working numexpr version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using numexpr is to evaluate every matrix expression on it's own. The following Code should output a python function which evaluates all matrix expressions using Numexpr.

**Numexpr with Matrices**

```
import numpy as np
import sympy

def lambdify_numexpr(args,expr,expr_name):
    from sympy.printing.lambdarepr import NumExprPrinter as Printer
    printer = Printer({'fully_qualified_modules': False, 'inline': True,'allow_unknown_functions': False})

    s=""
    s+="import numexpr as ne\n"
    s+="from numpy import *\n"
    s+="\n"

    #get arg_names
    arg_names=[]
    arg_names_str=""
    for i in range(len(args)):
        name=[ k for k,v in globals().items() if v is args[i]][0]
        arg_names_str+=name
        arg_names.append(name)

        if i< len(args)-1:
            arg_names_str+=","

    #Write header
    s+="def "+expr_name+"("+arg_names_str+"):\n"

    #unroll array
    for ii in range(len(args)):
        arg=args[ii]
        if arg.is_Matrix:
            for i in range(arg.shape[0]):
                for j in range(arg.shape[1]):
                    s+="    "+ str(arg[i,j])+" = " + arg_names[ii]+"["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]\n"

    s+="    \n"
    #If the expr is a matrix
    if expr.is_Matrix:
        #write expressions
        for i in range(len(expr)):
            s+="    "+ "res_"+str(i)+" = ne."+printer.doprint(expr[i])+"\n"
            s+="    \n"

        res_counter=0
        #write array
        s+="    return concatenate(("
        for i in range(expr.shape[0]):
            s+="("
            for j in range(expr.shape[1]):
                s+="res_"+str(res_counter)+","
                res_counter+=1
            s+="),"
        s+="))\n"

    #If the expr is not a matrix
    else:
        s+="    "+ "return ne."+printer.doprint(expr)+"\n"
    return s
```