# How to use repr() for functions stored in variables to retrieve their source code?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to be able to `repr()` on a class in python which has functions stored in the class's variables so I can reproduce the same functions later when I `eval()` said output.

Here's an example to illustrate my problem:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.func)


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


example = Example(add)
print(repr(example))
```

When I run that code, the output I get is:

`<function add at 0x7f6ea0e96e18>`

Is there any way of making a `repr()` which would output something that can then be `eval()`ed to a callable function. Ideally, I'd like an output like:

`def add(x, y): return x + y`

Comment: If it's a named function, you could just use the function name.  If it's a lambda, you could use the lambda expression.  But in either case, you won't get any parent context (if there is any), so there are limits to what you can do.

Comment: You might be able to use something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function , but this whole thing sounds like a really weird thing to do

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Python's [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) module:

```
import inspect


class Example:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __repr__(self):
        return inspect.getsource(self.func)


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


example = Example(add)
print(repr(example))
```

Output:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```