# How to find the exact location of a method in Python source code?

Tags: python

So in an `iPython terminal`, if you type a method followed by `??` you will get the source code and its location:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.angle??

Source:
@array_function_dispatch(_angle_dispatcher)
def angle(z, deg=False):
    z = asanyarray(z)
    if issubclass(z.dtype.type, _nx.complexfloating):
        zimag = z.imag
        zreal = z.real
    else:
        zimag = 0
        zreal = z

    a = arctan2(zimag, zreal)
    if deg:
        a *= 180/pi
    return a
File:      ~/Documents/venv_global/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py
Type:      function
```

How would I find the location of the source code (+the line number of the method) without entering into `iPython`.

PS:
(Removed the docstring from the output for readability).

Edit:

I am looking for something like a subcommand that I can run  which would give the information without needing to enter the shell. Not sure if it is possible though but it would look something like this:

```
ipython --source numpy.angle
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

Comment: @TankorSmash That was the question that I looked at before posting. All of them require you to enter a terminal.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to run python to execute python code. `inspect.getsource(foo) ` gives you the source, no?

Comment: @TankorSmash I was looking for a subcommand that I can add to iPython that will give it to me without having to enter the shell. For example: `ipython --source numpy.angle`. Though I do not know if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a docstring and source documentations and file path:

```py
import inspect
import numpy as np

print(np.angle.__doc__)
print('Source:')
print(inspect.getsource(np.angle))
print('File:')
print(inspect.getsourcefile(np.angle))
print('Type:')
print(type(np.angle))
```

The above code prints the docstrings, the source file path and type you get from `??` in iPython.

Comment: I believe that `??` in iPython goes one step further and gives you the location of the method.

Comment: I added that too. Use `inspect` to get extra details

Comment: The `inspect.getsourcefile(np.angle)` gives me `'<__array_function__ internals>'` not the exact file location. But you can add on to your answer `inspect.getsourcelines(np.angle)[1]`

Comment: Also, is there a way to run this without opening a python terminal?

Comment: Yes, instead on new line replaced above with `;` and the run in terminal `python -c "import inspect;import numpy as np;#..."

Comment: I see, I assume I would have to write it as a bash script that takes arguments for it to work. I'll accept your answer