# How to check if an instance attribute exists in an method Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I will get straight to the point. I have been trying to find different ways in which I can check if an instance attribute exists in a method of a class which has not been called from the instance of the class.

Consider the following example:

```
class Main:
    def thing1(self):
        self.x = 10
    
m = Main()
print(m.x)
```

This code above will not work, until I call the method, e.g:

```
class Main:
    def thing1(self):
        self.x = 10
    
m = Main()
m.thing1()
print(m.x)
```

or

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing1()

    def thing1(self):
        self.x = 10
    
m = Main()
print(m.x)
```

I want to know if there is a way I can check if this instance attribute exists in the method without having to call it.

I have tried using:

- hasattr()
- dir()
- __ dict __

None of them will show that I have a instance attribute called 'x' in thing1

As well as this, I would greatly appreciate it if you could show me how I could check if an instance attribute in a method exists through another method.

```
class Main:
    def thing1(self):
        self.x = 10
    
    def check(self):
        # Is there a way I can check if 'x' exists in the method names thing1, without having to call it.
    
m = Main()
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this question, and I hope that you have a great day!

Comment: Well, you *don't* have an instance attribute until you call the method. Which is why you should create all attributes in `__init__`, so this kind of confusion doesn't exist. Assignment is declaration, the attribute doesn't "exist" before it is being assigned to. Linters will warn when you assign to attributes not created in `__init__` for this reason.

Comment: "I have tried using: ``hasattr()`` ``dir()`` ``__ dict __``" Please show how you tried that, since these are exactly the ways to check for attributes. If they do *not* work, you are either using them wrong or are trying to do something that is no obvious from the description.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out which method sets/defines/modifies which attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `hasattr()` definitely works. See interactive example below:

```
>>> class Main:
...     def thing1(self):
...         self.x = 10
... 
>>> m = Main()
>>> hasattr(m, 'x')
False
>>> m.thing1()
>>> hasattr(m, 'x')
True
>>> print(m.x)
10
```

It's worth noting, though, that attributes should be initialized in the constructor. It's good practice to use `__slots__` to [declare attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), but they must still be initialized. Also, [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (attributes) are initialized outside the constructor. See example below:

```
class Main:
    c = 5
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 12
    def thing1(self):
        self.x = 10

m = Main()
print(hasattr(m, 'x'))
print(hasattr(m, 'y'))
print(m.c)
```

Output:

```
False
True
5
```

After reading the question again and additional comments, it seems that you want to access an attribute that is initalized in a method, without actually calling said method. This is not possible because the attribute won't actually exist until it is initialized.

The only way I can think of to determine if the attribute **would** exist after the method call, is to [read the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function) of the function in your program and check for the presence of the attribute. This is one crude example, which by no means is guaranteed to always work:

```
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(Main.thing1)
print('self.x' in lines)
```

The above, would print `True` for the code in question. I cannot think of a use case where this would be useful and strongly discourage it, but it's good to know the capabilities of Python.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think that there may be a bit of confusion on what I am asking because of how I phrased the question. I know that hasattr() works once I run the method, however I want to check if I can do this without having to run the method(e.g. is there a way in which I can run: hasattr(m, 'x')  - and get True back without having to run m.thing1() first)

Comment: Is your question how to check if an attribute exists, or how to assign an attribute? The only way `hasattr()` returns True is if the attribute exists. The attribute will exist if you initialize it in the constructor (e.g.  `__init__(self): self.x = 10`) or assign it later, as in your `thing1()` example.

Comment: Ok thank you. I guess that's the only way to do it.

Comment: I think I get what you meant now and updated the answer.