# Hash of a function implementation

Tags: python, hash, pickle

I'd like to cache intermediate results. I think that a decorator might help.

I not only want to cache based on function arguments, but also based on the implementation.

Background: I want to cache results between program runs because I am experimenting with the individual implementations, and I want to re-use results of the last run if possible.

It seems to be possible to get a function hash with `pickle`:

```py
from hashlib import sha256
import pickle

def foo(bar):
  print(bar)

h = sha256()
h.update(pickle.dumps(foo))
```

The next step would now be to use this in a decorator:

```py
from hashlib import sha256
import pickle

def decorated(f):
  def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    h = sha256()
    h.update(pickle.dumps((args, kwargs, f))
    print(h.hexdigest())
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  return inner

@decorated
def foo(bar):
  print(bar)

foo("bar")
```

Now `pickle` complains:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function foo at 0x7f3d177fdee0>: it's not the same object as __main__.foo
```

I can understand that my original function got re-assigned during the decoration and that this causes trouble (`foo=decorared(foo))`.

Is pickling the correct choice here at all?

*edit*

This question here shows how to get the source code of a method:
[How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function) – maybe that's the better approach?

Comment: No, the problem is you can't pickle nested functions like that. Basically, pickle just uses the name of the function, and then that name is looked up when you unpickle it.

Comment: Anyway, maybe just the raw bytecode would be sufficient for your purposes? `f.__code__.co_code`?

Comment: That seems to be a solution!

Comment: ... with a catch: in `f` when I instantiate an object and change the parameters, this seems not to be reflected in the `co_code`. `inspect.getsource()` contains the `@decorated` which seems ugly, but re-evaluating when I change the decorator name is something I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

*Is pickling the correct choice here at all?*

If you want to serialize python function and might use external modules, then you might use [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) for that purpose.