# What is the command to show function definitions in Xonsh?

Tags: xonsh

In Bash, if I create a function, I can use the `type` command to show me that function definition like so:

```
# define a function
foo {
    echo "bar"
}

# now show me that definition
$ type foo
foo is a function
foo ()
{
    echo "bar"
}
```

Zsh and Fish both have something similar with their `functions` commands. I checked the [bash-to-xsh page here](https://xon.sh/bash_to_xsh.html), but could not find an equivalent. I tried using Python's `inspect`, but that didn't work either:

```
def foo():
  echo "bar"

$ foo
<function __main__.foo>

$ import inspect as i
$ i.getsource(foo)
xonsh: For full traceback set: $XONSH_SHOW_TRACEBACK = True
OSError: could not get source code
```

How do you show method definitions in Xonsh?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a limitation of Python, and not really a problem with Xonsh, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function).

If the Xonsh function is defined in a file, `inspect` works. If the function is defined only in memory, it is not available.

For example, this code works:

```
import inspect
echo @(inspect.getsource($PROMPT_FIELDS['cwd']))
```

So does this:

```
import inspect
echo "def foo():\n\techo 'bar'\n" > foo.xsh
source foo.xsh
echo @(inspect.getsource(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:** Current versions of xonsh (e.g. 0.13.4) contain [superhelp](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#help-superhelp-with) where affixing `??` outputs information about the object.  It is an easier way to perform the inspection than using `inspect` module:

```bash
$ foo??

Type:         function
String form:  <function foo at 0x1084e58a0>
File:         /path/to/foo.xsh
Definition:   foo()
Source:
def foo():
    echo "bar"
```

**Unfortunately, it suffers from the same problem you describe in your own answer, that is that the source code would be displayed only for a function saved in a file.**