# How to show a code of a function imported in Python?

Tags: python, function

I'd like to know if I can somehow list/display the function that I'm importing in Python.
Let's say I have 2 files:

## functions.py

```py
def add(a,b):
    c = a + b
    print(c)
```

## calc.py

```py
from functions import *
```

So I want to see the whole code of the add() function without
checking the functions.py file. Is that possible? I found that functions are not iterable, thus I can't print them with a for loop.

Maybe it's silly or useless, but I have a function that's imported in Replit and I'd like to see the code of the function.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/427453/10703473

Comment: There's this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/427533/1076480, but perhaps your code has outgrown a repl.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidEhrmann!
This worked just fine in my code, but not in Replit.
`import inspect`
`lines = inspect.getsource(foo)`
`print(foo)`

Comment: Did you see the caveat? I'm guessing you're not really interested in an implementation of `add()`.

Comment: @DeLucasso how did it "not work". You really *must* give a proper problem specification. Note, the linked duplicate will not work for various kinds of functions, e.g. built-in functions, functions that are written as C-extensions, basically, only for functions that are written as standard Python modules.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thank you. .inspect worked for my functions that are in separate files, but returned "<function clear at 0x7fb5f44238b0>" in replit. I'm trying to get a code of clear() function in replit. import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(clear)
print(clear). Anyway, it's a silly try to see this code source, but I've learned here how to use .inspect outside replit.