# How to print expression of a function defined in "def" statement

Tags: python, function, output

I'am using a small program calculating by dichotomy the root of a function (i.e. find `x` when `f(x)=0`). (I admit I stole this program from some `SO` post, but I can't give the reference nor thank the author because I don't remember where it was...)

The output I have is:

```
Root is: -0.567143
Delta with 0 is:  0.000000000166
```

I would like to also output the expression of the function I am working on, just as written in `def f(x)` so as to have:

```
Function is: x + np.exp(x)
Root is: -0.567143
Delta with 0 is:  0.000000000166
```

I wonder how to do that...? Can `def f(x)` be modified to store the function writing somewhere? Or is it necessary to do another type of manipulation elsewhere?

**My program is:**

```
def samesign(a, b):
        return a * b > 0

def dichotomy(func, low, high, tolerance=None):
    
    # func(low) and func(high) must have opposite signs
    assert not samesign(func(low), func(high)), ("\n"
                                                 "Assertion failed!\n"
                                                 "Replace low or high")
    condition = True

    while condition:
        midpoint = (low + high) / 2.0
        if samesign(func(low), func(midpoint)):
            low = midpoint
        else:
            high = midpoint
        if tolerance is not None and abs(high - low) < tolerance:
            break   
        condition = abs(high - low) > tolerance

    return midpoint

def f(x):
    # Define function
    return x + np.exp(x)

x = dichotomy(f, -1, 0, 1E-9)

import inspect
line_return = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[0][-1]
llr = len(line_return)
name = line_return[11 : llr-1]

print(f'Function is: {name}')
print(f'Root is: {x: .6f}')
print(f'Delta with 0 is: {f(x): .12f}')
```

Comment: your function is statically defined as `x + np.exp(x)` inside the f function. so just statically do `print("Function is: x + np.exp(x)")` Changing the function requires changing the code, so if you change the code inside f to redefine the function also change the print statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

Comment: I could do that to retrieve the expression I want inside a variable that I could further print : `import inspect
line_return = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[0][-1]
llr = len(line_return)
name = line_return[11 : llr-1]
name`  but this is quite ugly... No better way?

Comment: In order to be clearer, I edited the code, now including the modifications displayed in my previous comment. Is it really the only way to do ? it seems a bit heavy and not very pythonic, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-fonction), you can get the full definition of the function with the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsource(f))
def f(x):
    # Define function
    return x + np.exp(x)
```

Note that function `f` [must be defined in a source file](https://bugs.python.org/issue12920).

If you are only interested in the content of the return statement, you must explore the [ast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the function to extract the return statement using of the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

```
import ast


def get_return_statement(fct):
    root = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f))
    try:
        return_node = next(
            node for node in ast.walk(root) if isinstance(node, ast.Return)
        )
        return ast.unparse(return_node.value)
    except StopIteration:
        return "None"
```

`get_return_statement(f)` will give you `x + np.exp(x)`.

**Edit for python prior to 3.9:**

`ast.unparse` is only available since python 3.9. It can be replace by the [`astor`](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) third party library, by replacing `ast.unparse` with [`astor.to_source`](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#id2).

The result is slightly different with more parentheses: `(x + np.exp(x))`.

Comment: Thanks! But after running `get_return_statement(f)` I have this error `module 'ast' has no attribute 'unparse'`. Could it be a version issue?

Comment: Adding: my Python version is `3.7.6`

Comment: You can use astor

Comment: OK. Thank you for that clarification !