# Late code evaluation and also printing the code

Tags: python, eval, late-binding

I want to pass code to a test() routine, which has to :

1. print the code
2. execute it
3. and finally do stuff with the result.
4. should handle args in the background

For quick code snippets I can use `eval(code-string)`, like this:

```
def test_eval(expr_str, expected):
    global a,b
    res = eval(expr_str) == expected
    print(f'{res} : {expr_str}')
```

but for:

- code with assignment
- `test()` should do argumentless calling of `fun()`, even for `fun(a, b...)`
- or longer code

the approach is unusable.

---

SOLVED

```
def test(fun,expected,args):
    res = fun(*args) == expected
    expr = inspect.getsource(fun)
    print(f'{res} : {expr}')


def tests():fun()
    def w(a,b):#args
        a += b #assignment
        return a.sym == "(a + b)"

    a = ...
    b = ...
    test(w,True,(a,b))
```

better ideas?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do, partly because you're relying on your code to demonstrate what you want, but your code is unrunnable and has a bunch of unexplained stuff in it.  What's `fun2str`?  What do you actually want the `tests()` function to do?  What does `#too long` mean?  What's the point of any of this -- are you trying to test your code, or are you trying to print it out, or what?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write unit tests, but your intention isn't clear.  If you're looking to test your functions, try either the `unittest` package (which uses OOP) or `pytest` (OOP not required)

Comment: test fwks are both too verbose to write and err reporting is not suitable to my case. I dont see they can print the code.. in short i have to recreate it ;)

Comment: If you want to print the source code of a function, use the `inspect` module function `getsource(function)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function