# Find Functions Stored in Running Python Kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, deleted-functions

I've done something stupid in Python, in Jupyter notebook. I deleted the cell that had my functions in it, probably a couple of hours ago, and now I don't have them any more. However, I can still run them, so they are still loaded in the kernel.

Is there a way to find that loaded kernel somewhere so I could copy those functions back into my code?

Thanks!

I've looked on the internet for ideas but haven't found anything.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function

Answer (score 1):

I found how to solve this. The `.getsource` does the work:

```
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(set_claims_rebates)
print(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, the Myth. Good edit!