How to use scipy.optimize.minimize with x defined through database updates
I have a black box optimization problem I am dealing with. Due to the nature of the black box, the vector (or set of vectors) x cannot be redefined programmatically during optimization. That is to say, x itself isn't passed to the black box directly, rather some x-equivalent defined in a database JSON file is passed.
It seems to me that I would have to read what the database says, call that x programmatically, and then update the database following the optimization iteration. To my knowledge, scipy.optimize.minimize can't work with an objective function defined this way. Is there any workaround, or will I have to define my own optimization functions by scratch?
Code
Alright, here is a snippet of code that is more or less what I am trying to achieve.
# Sum of sum of squared differences function
def sum_ssd(y1, y2):
    ssd_y1 = np.sum((y1-y1_data)**2)
    ssd_y2 = np.sum((y2-y2_data)**2)
    sum_that = ssd_y1 + ssd_y2
    return sum_that

# Objective function
def objective(x12):
    # Separate opt input into BB inputs
    x1 = x12[:5]
    x2 = x12[5:]
    # Update BB inputs in database
    json_obj[some_index]["x1"]=x1.tolist()
    json_obj[some_index]["x2"]=x2.tolist()
    with open(file_path, "w") as json_fp:
        json.dump(json_obj, json_fp, indent = 4)
    # Black Box - db_param changes with database changes
    y1 = bb(db_param, param1)
    y2 = bb(db_param, param2)
    # Sum of SSDs
    out = sum_ssd(y1, y2)
    return out

# Callback function
def callback(x):
    print(x)
    print(objective(x))

# Set up x0 equivalent
with open(file_path, "r") as json_fp:
    json_obj = json.load(json_fp)
x1 = json_obj[some_index]["x1"]
x2 = json_obj[some_index]["x2"]
x1 = np.asarray(x1)
x2 = np.asarray(x2)
x012 = np.append(x1, x2)

# Perform optimization and finish up
res = sp.optimize.minimize(objective, x012, method='Nelder-Mead', callback=callback, options={'disp':True})

So for this example, I have x1 and x2 are arrays of 5 elements, and to trick minimize into handling a multivariate input I use x012. As for why Nelder-Mead, I dont know if the black box is always differentiable, but it is always continuous. When I run the code, the minimize executes but nothing seems to happen to x1 and x2 in the database.
Edit: What I've tried at this point...

Changing how the database is updated, as according to @NickODell 's comments.
Changing x2.tolist() to [1, 2] to see if the database actually gets updated - it does.
Creating a callback function to show me what happens to x and objective(x) after every iteration. The answer is nothing.
Using other algorithms for non-differentiable objective functions, like 'Powell'. No change. Just for the record, Nelder-Mead completes 14 iterations (1119 function evaluations), and Powell completes 1 iteration (235 function evaluations) before giving up.

Also, since I am not using differentiable functions, I do not think this should be caused by an "exploding gradient" (see this). So at this point I am at a loss. I know it's a general question - there is no code shown for the black box or how param1 and param2 get defined.

Minimize has a callback option that can call function on each step of the solver.

Why wouldn't you load x0 from the file into memory, alter your function to accept getting numbers rather than a file, and pass that to minimize? Is there some reason your black box must interact with a database? Is this a memory limitation? Are you working with closed source code?

@NickODell I have to call the black box in my objective function, and the black box effectively takes x0 from the database rather than from the arguments in the objective function. The black box is not closed source but it is not my code and the math in it is beyond me, I don't want to break it by trying to modify it.

What would stop you from writing an objective function which 1) writes the x0 value to the database 2) calls the black box function, and 3) reads the value of the objective function back from the database?

I think it would help to distinguish between x0 - the initial guess passed to minimize - from x, the value minimize passes to the objective function. Which do you mean?

Regardless of the form of the initial value you give to minimize, it is converted (if possible) to a 1d float array.  That is tweaked repeatedly, and passed to your objective function, which should return a scalar.  float.  Your function can modify that x into what ever form is convenient for the calculation.  Keep in mind though that the objective function will be called many times, so try to keep it simple and fast.

@NickODell I've attempted that.

@hpaulj I think I've done the 1D float array stuff you've described now in my code example.

"When I run the code, the minimize executes but nothing seems to happen to x1 and x2 in the database." Are you flushing your writes? Python buffers writes. The simplest way to do that is to open and close your file using a context manager. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

@NickODell I'm not sure. I made changes based on what you sent, and it still behaves the same way. If I force the objective function to print json_obj[some_index]["x1"] on every iteration, I can see it is never modified.

You should include the code you're trying in the question.

@NickODell Code snippet is modified to reflect my changes.

Thanks. "If I force the objective function to print [...] I can see it is never modified." I'm surprised by that. Where is this print statement? Is it inside objective() or bb()? Are you sure it's not just changing by a small amount? Nelder-Mead starts by changing each parameter by only 5%.

@NickODell Alright I am getting a soft notice to cut it out with the extended discussion in the comments. The print was in the objective function, following the json object updates. And yes, no changes at all; printing out in the objective function shows that. If I change x2.tolist() to instead [1, 2], I can see that change in the database, at least. To me, it's like minimize isn't modifying x12 (starting from x012) in any way during iteration.

Is the black box code in Python? If it's at all well designed, you should be able to import a function from it instead of performing a slow, awkward disk-based IPC.

This answer shows it is feasible to interact with the DB even without callback.
First we provide missing piece of codes, mainly:

A simple JSON as a Database
Dummy datasets
Dummy black box function

For instance:
# Create DB:
data = {
    "p": {
        "x1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "x2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
    }
}

with open("db.json", "w") as handler:
    json.dump(data, handler)

# Create some datasets:
n = 30
y1_data = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y2_data = np.linspace(-1, 0, n)


# Whatever black box function:
def bb(db_params, params):
    """No idea of what this function does"""
    return np.sum(db_params * params) * np.linspace(-1, 1, n)

Now we adapt your code to interact with the JSON Database at each step:
# Sum of sum of squared differences function
def sum_ssd(y1, y2):
    ssd_y1 = np.sum((y1-y1_data)**2)
    ssd_y2 = np.sum((y2-y2_data)**2)
    sum_that = ssd_y1 + ssd_y2
    return sum_that

# Objective function
def objective(x12):
    
    # Separate opt input into BB inputs
    x1 = x12[:5]
    x2 = x12[5:]
    
    # Write to DB:
    db = {
        "p": {
            "x1": x1.tolist(),
            "x2": x2.tolist()
        }
    } 
    with open("db.json", "w") as handler:
        json.dump(db, handler)
    
    # Black Box - db_param changes with database changes
    # Ensure function signature here!
    y1 = bb(x1, x1)
    y2 = bb(x2, x2)

    # Sum of SSDs
    out = sum_ssd(y1, y2)
    return out


def callback(x):
    with open("db.json", "r") as handler:
        print(json.load(handler))


# Read from DB:
with open("db.json", "r") as handler:
    db = json.load(handler)

x1 = db["p"]["x1"]
x2 = db["p"]["x2"]

x1 = np.asarray(x1)
x2 = np.asarray(x2)

x012 = np.append(x1, x2)

# Perform optimization and finish up
res = optimize.minimize(objective, x012, method='Nelder-Mead', callback=callback)

The additional callback is not required, but we used it to check the JSON DB is updated content at each step. It can be confirmed by running the current code.
#...
#{'p': {'x1': [0.5635924679456159, 0.37744611037456866, 0.16889467850450193, 0.08056540458960171, 0.06987014247935036], 'x2': [-0.4420054776612644, 0.4365207767214855, -0.25828873817490783, 0.2155649422026483, 0.02998456765120435]}}
#{'p': {'x1': [0.5635974343191635, 0.37744623780370357, 0.16888311231741251, 0.0805657374136636, 0.06985568009797576], 'x2': [-0.44201141928424603, 0.43652230546899895, -0.2582863842239018, 0.21555487781815993, 0.029980534312484618]}}
#...
#       message: Optimization terminated successfully.
#       success: True
#        status: 0
#           fun: 15.000000000000522
#             x: [ 5.636e-01  3.774e-01  1.689e-01  8.056e-02  6.985e-02
#                 -4.420e-01  4.365e-01 -2.583e-01  2.156e-01  2.997e-02]
#           nit: 130
#          nfev: 258

Parameters are updated and with this setup, the optimization ends successfully. If you have only one step and the optimization succeed you may have already the right solution stored into your database.

Thank you for your answer. I am just a bit confused about something: does this code function any differently from my code example if my example provided the code you do for the BB, the data, etc.? Like, does your way of defining and rewriting the database differ from mine? If not, then clearly my code should work the same and my not seeing any change with iteration is due to some bug I am not seeing.

It's difficult to say without having a [mcve], this is why I provided the missing piece of code. The main difference with your code is that I don't use any global variable and I have ensured that the minimization can evolve towards a solution (directly linked to bb). Perhaps having some dummy bb function closer to real use case would help to understands why. Also it is not clear in your code what are param1 and param2 and which values they get (are they global, do they change?). The most closer we get to the [mcve] the better are your chance to be answered.

About the black box, you can use inspect module to check out the source code of it. That would be less black box and might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function

I will return to this question to provide a more reproducible example for the BB, etc. when I am able as I think it is a good question that I haven't seen elsewhere on SO. I just solved my issue - my problem was that the database changes should be reflected in an object that is passed to the BB as well, but to actually see any effect required said object to be reinitialized. So I will update my code with a good example of this so future readers have a good jumping off point. Thank you!
