# Python reflection - Can I use this to get the source code of a method definition

Tags: python, reflection

**Duplicate of..**

- [How can I get the code of python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-code-of-python-function)
- [print the code which defined a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334851/print-the-code-which-defined-a-lambda-function)
- [Python: How do you get Python to write down the code of a function it has in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399991/python-how-do-you-get-python-to-write-down-the-code-of-a-function-it-has-in-memo)

---

I have a method definition which is successfully running, but would like to modify it in runtime.

for eg:
If i have a method

```
def sayHello():
    print "Hello"
```

type(sayHello) gives me the answer 'type function'. Will I able to get the source code string of this function object. Is it considered a security issue ?

Comment: You cannot do this.  Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-code-of-python-function; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334851/print-the-code-which-defined-a-lambda-function; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399991/python-how-do-you-get-python-to-write-down-the-code-of-a-function-it-has-in-memo

Comment: It's Python: you already have the source.

Comment: I would strongly recommend asking another question with more details.  I have the funniest feeling that what you really want to do might only require closures/decorators, but because all you've asked about is print source code (and try to modify it somehow) you're getting disappointing answers.

Answer (score 26):

Use the inspect module:

```
import inspect
import mymodule
print inspect.getsource(mymodule.sayHello)
```

The function must be defined in a module that you import.

Comment: I had to use brackets around everything ie "print(inspect.getsource(mymodule.sayHello))", I think that's a Python3 thing.

Answer (score 5):

To get the source of a method on a class instance do:

```
import inspect
myobj = MyModel()
print inspect.getsource(myobj.my_method)
```

Read more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource

Answer (score 3):

`sayHello.func_code.co_code` returns a string that I think contains the compiled code of the method. Since Python is internally compiling the code to virtual machine bytecode, this might be all that's left.

You can disassemble it, though:

```
import dis

def sayHello():
  print "hello"

dis.dis(sayHello)
```

This prints:

```
   1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
               3 PRINT_ITEM
               4 PRINT_NEWLINE
               5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
               8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Have a look at [Decompyle](http://www.crazy-compilers.com/decompyle/) for a de-compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in function to get source code of a function, however, you could build you own if you have access to the source-code (it would be in your Python/lib directory).