# How to see/print a function saved in a variable but with deleted code?

Tags: python, function

I am working on a script and have accidentally deleted the code of a function a while back (so cant Undo) but the function is saved in the memory.

```
print(diff)

#output
<function diff at 0x7f48f238a670>
```

Is there a way to print this function's code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get Python to write down the code of a function it has in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399991/how-do-you-get-python-to-write-down-the-code-of-a-function-it-has-in-memory)

Comment: @MurtazaHaji: That relies on the source file still existing.

Comment: Not if the source code is gone.

Comment: I would start with retrieving the bytecode using [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) and then try to convert back to python using [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/) or similar, depending on the actual python version.

Comment: This might help maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8250625/12134794