# Is it possible to programmatically inspect the code of a function?

Tags: python, function, oop, introspection

Assuming I have a (mathematical) function hyperbolic (it can also be a lambda function):

```
def hyperbolic(x):
    return a*x + b
```

I know its possible to pass it in another function and get the name (and other parameters) like so:

```
def inspect(func):
   print (func.__name__)
```

My question is:

> is it possible to printout the actual mathematical code of the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399991/how-do-you-get-python-to-write-down-the-code-of-a-function-it-has-in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399991/how-do-you-get-python-to-write-down-the-code-of-a-function-it-has-in-memory)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _the actual mathematical code of the function_, e.g. in the example case?