# How can I use inspect.getsource from within a dynamically executed string of code?

Tags: python

If I have this code in a file:

```py
import inspect

def sample(p1):
    print(p1)
    return 1

print(inspect.getsource(sample))
```

When I run the script, it works as expected: on the last line, the source code for the `sample` function is printed.

However, if I create a string with that same code, and supply it to `exec`, like so:

```py
source = """import inspect

def sample(p1):
    print(p1)
    return 1

print(inspect.getsource(sample))
"""

exec(source)
```

This fails with the message `OSError: could not get source code`.

How can I make this work while using `exec` to run the code - with the call to `inspect.getsource` being *part of the dynamically-executed code string*?

Comment: _For example when i feed the following code as a string into exec(code)_ Yes...? What happens? _So does anyone know how i could get the source inside the exec()?_ What is this for?

Comment: You cannot. This is one of the limitations of dynamically executing a string as code.

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, as I'm sure you've realised, this simply is not possible using `exec`...but it is possible using `exec_module`.

If you are not required to use `exec` specifically, this may work for you:

```
import tempfile
from importlib import util
import importlib.machinery

raw = """
def sample(p1):
    print(p1)
    return 1

import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(sample))
"""

# Create a temporary source code file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as tmp:
    tmp.write(raw.encode())
    tmp.flush()

    # Now load that file as a module
    spec = util.spec_from_file_location('tmp', tmp.name)
    module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    # ...or, while the tmp file exists, you can query it externally
    import inspect
    print(inspect.getsource(module.sample))
```

The TLDR is, without a source file, it is just flat out not-possible to use `getsource` to read the source code of a function, because the implementation reads the source code from the file defined in `f.__code__.co_filename` on the function (read-only, so monkey patching is impossible).

However, if you write the source code to a temporary file, you can load that file as a module (`exec_module` is practically identical to the effect of `exec`, you just have to do a few other steps first).

Note: `tmp.flush()` <-- don't forget this, `tmp.write()` doesn't write until you flush, and you'll be 'loading' an empty file if you don't flush it first.

Comment: Instead of this chicanery: `if '' not in importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES:` can't you just use something like `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as tmp: ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, that's probably a better solution. Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated the answer with your comment. Much nicer~

Comment: "because the implementation reads the source code from the file defined in `f.__code__.co_filename` on the function" - more precisely, from the file *named by* `f.__code__.co_filename`, which *is a string with a path to the file* (when there is a file). So the problem can't be solved by using e.g. a `StringIO` file-like object, because `f.__code__.co_filename`  will simply be `'<string>'`, not the `StringIO` instance.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is like this:

```py
exec("""\
import inspect

def sample(p1):
    print(p1)
    return 1

print(inspect.getsource(sample))\
""")
```

And the exception is `OSError: could not get source code` then that probably means that `inspect.getsource()` requires a
file's source to inspect. `exec` [dynamically executes Python code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) so the `sample` function that's being defined from `exec` is not stored in a file.

Something like this:

```py
def sample(p1):
    print(p1)
    return 1

exec("""\
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(sample))\
""")
```

would work because the function `sample` is defined in the source code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Your answer explains my question why it doesn't work, but your fix sadly doesn't work for me because I have to have the function and the `inspect.getsource (sample)` in the exec string. Do you have any ideas how I could get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can solve this issue without using temporary files.

Apparently, this exact issue was encountered during the development of the builtin `doctest` module. This is even mentioned in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e4c3efec17da14d26cd512a7ec97ee8ddd8a9f7/Lib/inspect.py#L1069) of `inspect`. It turns out that reading source files is done through the `linecache.getlines` function. What `doctest` does it that it [swaps](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e4c3efec17da14d26cd512a7ec97ee8ddd8a9f7/Lib/doctest.py#L1488) that function for its own [wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e4c3efec17da14d26cd512a7ec97ee8ddd8a9f7/Lib/doctest.py#L1432). Based on this, we can create an analogous patch for `exec`:

```py
def better_exec(code_, globals_=None, locals_=None, /, *, closure=None):
    import ast
    import linecache

    if not hasattr(better_exec, "saved_sources"):
        old_getlines = linecache.getlines
        better_exec.saved_sources = []

        def patched_getlines(filename, module_globals=None):
            if "<exec#" in filename:
                index = int(filename.split("#")[1].split(">")[0])
                return better_exec.saved_sources[index].splitlines(True)
            else:
                return old_getlines(filename, module_globals)

        linecache.getlines = patched_getlines
    better_exec.saved_sources.append(code_)
    exec(
        compile(
            ast.parse(code_),
            filename=f"<exec#{len(better_exec.saved_sources) - 1}>",
            mode="exec",
        ),
        globals_,
        locals_,
        closure=None,
    )
```

It works even if you try to get the source code from within the `exec`:

```
>>> namespace_ = {}
>>> better_exec("""\
... def foo():
...     print("foo")
... import inspect
... foo_source = inspect.getsource(foo)
... """, namespace_)
>>> print(namespace_["foo_source"])
def foo():
    print("foo")
>>> namespace_["foo"]()
foo
```

Each call to `exec` stores its input in the `better_exec.saved_sources` array. As such, if there are many calls to it, this could potentially cause high memory usage. This could be solved, for example, by swapping some of these sources to disk or simply deleting them.

If you are getting an `OSError: source code not available` from within `inspect`, make sure that your filename (`<exec#...>` here) begins with `<` and ends with `>`.

Note that while this successfully exposes the code to `inspect`, and `pdb`, it is, unfortunately, not visible in native exception stack traces:

```py
>>> namespace_ = {}
>>> better_exec("""\
... def f():
...     raise RuntimeError()
... """, namespace_)
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsource(namespace_["f"])) # Works!
def f():
    raise RuntimeError()
>>> namespace_["f"]()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/output.s", line 37, in <module>
    namespace_["f"]() # No source :(
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<exec#0>", line 2, in f
RuntimeError
```

As as sidenote, if you are using VSCode, then by [disabling Just My Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448/how-to-disable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger), you will even be able to step through the code given to `exec`:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a neat technique. However, can you ensure that the `inspect.getsource` call will work *as part of the string being `exec`ed? (Does it work already?) That seems to have been a key part of the original requirement (which I tried to preserve in the most recent edit to the question).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I indeed didn't pay enough attention to this requirement about `inspect.getsource` also being `exec`ed. I actually edited the question because the wording was a bit unclear to me, and I missed this point. After a minor edit, this requirement is now also met. Thanks for pointing this out!