# Python 3 how can I print lambda expression?

Tags: python, regex, lambda, printing

How can I print the inside of a lambda function?

For example, from the following lambda expression:

```
lambda a, b: a / b
```

I want to receive:

```
a / b
```

Or from this expression:

```
lambda a, b: math.pow(a, b)
```

To receive:

```
pow(a, b)
```

Comment: A lambda is a function. You're asking to print the source code of the function in nicely human readable format. You can't just do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function)

Comment: Another good question would be why would you want to do this? maybe there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Why/how should `lambda a, b: math.pow(a, b)` result in just `pow(a, b)`…?

Comment: I don't think the tagged question has a direct answer for the question. It only has explained how to get the source code. using the same inspect library you can apply a regular expression to get what is needed. I dont see a reason to downvote or close this question

Comment: It is already answered  :


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334851/print-the-code-which-defined-a-lambda-function

Comment: lambda itself is a just a function without name being declared, you can set the name with `function_name = lambda function`